.NET 8 app appsettings.json transformation for Azure container app migration
We've got a .NET 8.0 web app that currently working in an Azure web app that we want to start deploying as an Azure container app. We've got a load of similar application and feel that the azure container app model would better suit the direction we are moving in.
I've containerized the build and am able to deploy it to a container app. However, the application is running with an unconfigured appsettings.json file and hence is not running correctly.
We use Azure DevOps for deployment. In the web app deployment we have use the file transform yaml task to transform the appsettings file from a series of secrets into the state that we want it before the deployment to the web app.

Is there a similar task for azure container apps (hopefully within Azure DevOps).  Even more basic than that, I'm yet to understand how the appsettings.json file can be transformed during deployment to an Azure Container App. Alternatively do I have to setup each variable in the container app as an environment variable? Isn't there some way I can just create the secrets and get the appsettings file to be transformed?
Basically, as we having to convert a number of .NET apps, it would be more helpful if we could transform the appsettings file with one command as we can with the file transform task, or something similar to that.

Hi @ossentoo, Have you got a chance to check the answer below to modify appsettings.json or update environment variables for your container app? Hope it could help resolve your concern in this post. Appreciate your time and sharing.

you can use env var,  what about key vault secrets ?

Did you try to configure environment variables on your Container App to pick up secrets? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/container-apps/environment-variables In that way you can use the same container image and deploy to different Container Apps, where the secrets can vary to meet your needs. appsettings.json shouldn't contain anything that depends on deployed environment.

You may consider using the extension task replacetokens@6 to to replace placeholder values like #{VariableName}# in your appsettings.json with corresponding pipeline variable values during the build process before building your app image.
Additionally, you can use a PowerShell script to extract environment variables defined in the appsettings.json file, and subsequently use those values to set environment variables for your Azure Container App during the deployment process via the AzureContainerApps@1 task. See more information on Set variables in scripts
Below is a sample configuration for your reference:
/src/appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ENV_VAR_1": "XXX",
  "ENV_VAR_2": "YYY",
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "testAlbum": {
    "Id": "#{Build.BuildId}#",
    "Title": "Alvin's Album",
    "Artist": "Alvin Zhao",
    "Price": 99.99,
    "Image_url": "https://azalbum.com"
  }
}

azure-pipelines.yml
variables:
  # ACR info
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'ACRSvcCnnWIF'
  imageRepository: 'containerapp/dotnet/sample'
  containerRegistry: 'azacrrxxxxxx.azurecr.io'
  myAcr: azacrxxxxxx
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Azure container app info
  ARMSvcCnn: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFSub0'
  appName: 'azcontainerappxxxxxx'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: CI_CD
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
    - task: replacetokens@6
      inputs:
        sources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/appsettings.json'
      displayName: Replace testAlbum.Id in appsettings with the value of the pipeline Build.BuildId
    - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/appsettings.json
      artifact: appsettings
    - pwsh: |
        # Read the JSON file and parse it
        $jsonFilePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/appsettings.json"
        $jsonContent = Get-Content $jsonFilePath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

        # Extract the variables
        $ENV_VAR_1 = $jsonContent.ENV_VAR_1
        $ENV_VAR_2 = $jsonContent.ENV_VAR_2

        # Set the environment variables for downstream tasks
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ENV_VAR_1]$ENV_VAR_1"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ENV_VAR_2]$ENV_VAR_2"
      displayName: Output environment variables from appsettings.json
    - task: AzureContainerApps@1
      displayName: Build app image and push to ACR
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
        appSourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src'
        acrName: '$(myAcr)'
        containerAppName: '$(appName)'
        resourceGroup: 'rg-azcontainerapp'
        imageToBuild: $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
    - task: AzureContainerApps@1
      displayName: Deploy image to container app
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
        acrName: '$(myAcr)'
        imageToDeploy: '$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'
        containerAppName: '$(appName)'
        resourceGroup: 'rg-azcontainerapp'
        environmentVariables: >
          BUILD_BUILDID=$(Build.BuildId)
          ENV_VAR_1=$(ENV_VAR_1)
          ENV_VAR_2=$(ENV_VAR_2)


ok thanks.  I would rather build the same image for all environments.  We're investigating using the double underscore method

Hi @ossentoo, Thanks for sharing the updated requirement to use the same image; then you may have a test to use the script in my answer to output variables from the appsettings.json file to be used by AzureContainerApps@1 task for image deployment and container environment variables update. If you have better options, we would appreciate you could briefly introduce your solution in the answer section. Thx for your time and sharing. Have a lovely weekend.

Double underscore works as we've amended the startup in our dotnet app by using: builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables(); The app is then able to read environment variables setup in the container app during startup.

Thanks a lot for sharing the method to use builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables().

In portal.azure.com go to the web app, do you have a settings -> Environment variables tag? or settings -> Configuration?
Environment variables are the appsettings.json variables. Where an multi level variable should be replaced with parent__child
